# How to get viewModel in my class MainFragment : BrowseSupportFragment(), I use Hilt

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

How to get viewModel in my class MainFragment : BrowseSupportFragment(), I use Hilt? !! app relate to TV module!!
The issue is: when I try get viewModel in my fragment **..."viewModels()"** highlighted by red.

My app is Android TV module.

build.gradle(Module:tv):

```
dependencies {
//hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'
    
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
}
```

My Fragment:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainFragment : BrowseSupportFragment() {
        
        private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
...
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val usecase: CategoryUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean? is viewModel variable null? do you have errors while compiling the app? please be more specific in the question above. thanks

Comment: The issue is: when I try get viewModel in my fragment **..."viewModels()"** highlighted by red.

Comment: please try with viewModels(), not ViewModels().

Comment: yes it should be with ..."viewModels()", but it's not a success ((, Even I made a new Blank fragment heritage from Fragment() and try get viewModel there not success as well!!

Comment: One important think which I have to highlighted the app relate to TV module